# What is a wasserstein barycenter?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, machine-learning, wasserstein

I am currently studying a paper on [Wasserstein Fair Classification](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.12059). Several places they mention the *Wasserstein barycenter*, *weighted barycenter distribution* or the *Wasserstein barycenter distribution*. What is it? How is it defined? I can only find very deep measure-theoretic explanations, which are both a bit out of my league as a statistician, who never enjoyed analysis very much, but they simply also lack an intuition behind.

Comment: You can have a look at this book [An Invitation to Statistics in Wasserstein Space](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-38438-8).